# Optimize speed on 400GB MyISAM table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam

We have MariaDB server with single table with image url information. The table is about 400GB on disk and contains probably 400M rows.

Table is partitioned in 1024 partitions.

All queries are similar to this one:

```
select * from container where id in (1234, 1235 ... );
```

The sql usually took 2 sec to be executed.

Each row contains a single image url, a title and keywords.

Keybufer is set to 8GB.

This set up works well, until we begin to insert aditioan rows. We tried normal inserts, also low_priority inserts. It is slow in both cases.

I wonder what else we can tweak in order to speed up the selects.

**Update**:
the table has no indexes, except the primary key on a bigint field e.g. primary key(id)

**Update 2**:
Here is some more information:

**Create Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `container` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `data` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=binary
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (id)
PARTITIONS 1024 */
```

`data` field stores standard JSON. It is UTF8 text, but because of wrong encoding of the input data, we were forced to store it in blob + binary encoding.

**Size on disk**

```
# du -h /usr/local/mysql/var/mydb/
371G    /usr/local/mysql/var/mydb/
```

**Count(*)**

```
> select count(*) from container;
+-----------+
| count(*)  |
+-----------+
| 409036295 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

**my.ini**

```
[mysqld]
server-id = 1

port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
skip_name_resolve

open-files-limit=64000

#Flush every 5 min (300 sec)
set-variable = flush_time=900

#Max Clients
set-variable = max_connections=5050
set-variable = max_user_connections=5000
set-variable = back_log=50

set-variable = table_open_cache=1024
set-variable = table_definition_cache=1024

#INSERT While SELECT-ing. Default is 1 (1 = On if have no hole, 2 = On if have hole)
set-variable = concurrent_insert=2

#Interactive timeout 60 min (from console)
set-variable = interactive_timeout=3600

#non-interactive timeout 3 hours
set-variable = wait_timeout=10800

set-variable = key_buffer_size=8192M
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=5M
set-variable = sort_buffer_size=256M

set-variable = tmp_table_size=512M
set-variable = max_heap_table_size=64M

#all updates will wait for selects
set-variable = low_priority_updates=1

#preforking
set-variable = thread_cache_size=64

#----- SLOW QUERIES -----

set-variable = long_query_time=2
set-variable = log_slow_queries=mysql-slow.log

#----- CASHE -----

# SELECT SQL_CACHE * from x
set-variable = query_cache_type=0
set-variable = query_cache_limit=1M
set-variable = query_cache_size=128M
```

Comment: Some questions: what do you feel slow, reads (SELECT) or writes (INSERT) performance? Can you post your /etc/my.cnf file and server specification? Have you tried to analyze your queries with MySQL integrated performance profiling?

Comment: i care only about select's speed. insert can be slow, no probl.

Comment: Something seems vaguely _wrong_ about storing 400 million blobs in a database...

Comment: is not binary. is json's as txt. I'll add information.

Comment: Err...maybe you should be using MongoDB then?

Comment: mongo failed already :) we do not search inside JSON. We use JSON because this is how the data "come" to us, but also it can help us if we want to migrate to Cassandra or some other nosql. All we need is get JSON string by its numeric key.

Comment: MyISAM table??? I would like to remind that MyISAM has only table level locks. So while your INSERT statement is running SELECT statements has to wait for lock to be released.

Comment: How is your table partitioned? (what type of partition are you using)

Comment: How large if your table? Why do you need big int? (that's 8 bytes). I would use int unsigned. Your PK is probably taking close to 3GB. You could cut that in half. If Id you're inserting are sequential, i would go with innodb + better also when dealing with insert/ select on same table

Comment: MyISAM - this is what I usually use. I know MyISAM have table level lock. Key is bigint, because this is the original data type from input data - 64 bit int. Table is partitioned "PARTITION BY KEY (id) PARTITIONS 1024". Insert key is random, usually increasing, but not always.

Comment: Let do some profiling. Execute the following SQL statement: `SET profiling = 1; SELECT * from container where id in (1234, 1235 ... ); SHOW profiles; SHOW profile for query 1; SET profiling = 0;` and show us the output.

Comment: I just did profiling (and I see what you mean), but we are not inserting at the moment. Will update it tomorrow when we are doing some inserts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did profiling MyISAM without partitioning and it was slower.

We did test InnoDB and we succeed to speed up inserts, but selects were still not as fast as we wanted.

Later, we did migration to TokuDB.

Because of TokuDB, at the moment table is about 100 GB and queries are very very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are `SELECTing` only by the `PRIMARY KEY`, then the following will speed it up:

- *NO* `PARTITIONing`.  It only slows down such queries, especially because of 1024 partitions.
- Switch to InnoDB.  The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data; this will save a disk hit on each row fetched.  Shrink `key_buffer_size` to 50M and raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of available RAM.  InnoDB also avoids table locks.
- Compress, in the client, the JSON text; the datatype needs to be `BLOB` (as it mistakenly is now).

Note:  InnoDB will expand the disk space by a factor of 2-3; the compression will get that space back.  (Please test this with, say, a million rows.  Experiment with the different `ROW_FORMATs`; I don't know which one will work best for your situation.  And validate the `SELECT` speed and the lack of interference between reads and writes.)

Do you really have 5000 connections at the same time?  They are probably stumbling over each other and slowing down each other.

You have half turned off the Query cache; also do `query_cache_size=0`